# Using SED on code that include parentheses

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to make this code

```
http("request_0").get(uri3 + "replacement_text")
```

look like this

```
http("replacement_text").get(uri3 + "replacement_text")
```

I am able to do that using the following SED command:

```
sed -i '/.*http(".*")$/{s/(.*\(\.get\((".*")\)\)$/\2\1/;}' .\test.txt
```

This command however doesn't work when the code looks like this and I think it is because of the parenthesis in front of htpp.

```
something(http("replacement_text").get(uri3 + "replacement_text"))
```

Comment: You escaped the parenthesis in `get\(`. Why did you choose to not do the same for `http(`?

Comment: That is for grouping. If I added the parenthesis for it would look something like this: 
`sed -i '/.*http\((".*")\)$/{s/(.*\(\.get\((".*")\)\)$/\2\1/;}'`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It does nothing?

Comment: When there is a parenthesis in front of http it changes to this: 
`something(uri3 + "replacement_text".get(uri3 + "replacement_text"))`
When it should be this 
`(http("uri3 + "replacement_text"))").get(uri3 + "replacement_text"))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to change the lines:

```
http("request_0").get(uri3 + "replacement_text")
something(http("request_0").get(uri3 + "replacement_text"))
```

into:

```
http("replacement_text").get(uri3 + "replacement_text")
something(http("replacement_text").get(uri3 + "replacement_text"))
```

then would you please try:

```
sed -i 's/\(http("\)[^"]\+\(.*get([^"]*"\)\([^"]\+\)/\1\3\2\3/' test.txt
```